# Accented letter and quotation marks in html innertext

Tags: c#, html, string, text

I take text from an html page but when I go to print on the screen accented letters and symbols like these: << >> or this: «», are represented by a question mark.

Example code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var html = @"<body>
                    <p>This is the text with «quotation marks» and accented word wè</p>
                 </body>";

    var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
    htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);

    var htmlNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");

    Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(WebUtility.HtmlDecode(htmlNodes.InnerText), @"\r\n?|\n|[ ]{2,}", ""));
    Console.ReadLine();
        
}
```

I already use WebUtility.HtmlDecode(string) for decode string and used HtmlAgilityPack for manage Html

> In the code example I wrote above the string returned is correct  with real characters:
>
> -- This is the text with «quotation marks» and accented word wè
>
> But in my case taking code in an html page (in the same illustrated way above) accented letters and symbols such as quotation marks print them with the question mark like this:
>
> -- This is the text with ?quotation marks? and accented word w?

How can I keep the real letters when are they shown with the question mark?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would really help if you could provide a [mcve] - at the moment we don't know how you're fetching the text, or how you're printing it on the screen.

Comment: I have updated the post more clearly

Comment: You're writing to the console - does your console even support those characters? If you just write `Console.WriteLine(html);` what does *that* show? You might want to use `chcp 65001` in your console before running the code.

Comment: Could I have a small example of how to use the chcp 65001 in the console?

Comment: In the console, you type "chcp 65001" (without the quotes) and hit return. It's as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

See https://www.whatsmyip.org/html-characters/ for a list of codes for special characters.  For example, è should be coded as `&#232;`

Comment: The problem is that in the string it doesn't show me "&#232" but just a question mark

Comment: I have already tried to replace but this don't fix the problem

Comment: The HTML is apparently correct. It is the printing to the console that is the issue - and that isn't helped by an HTML encoding

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Apparently.  At the time when I answered, the original question had less context and no sample code, so encoding was my best guess.